# Using -presentModalViewController:animated: with UITabBarController NOT animated

Tags: objective-c, ios

So the `rootViewController` for this application is a `UITabBarController` subclass. And we're having a bizarre issue where we cannot get a `UITabBarController` to `-presentModalViewController:animated:` if we're passing `NO` to animated. We've tried a variety of methods: `-viewDidLoad`, `-viewWillAppear`, `-viewDidAppear` and can only get it to work if we do it after a delay, which is hacky.

I decided to break this out into a test and found that if I have a `UIViewController` that calls `-presentModalViewController:animated:` in the `-viewDidAppear` method it works as expected with both `YES` and `NO` for the `animated` parameter. However if this VC is instead a `UITabBarController`, it works if `animated` is `YES` but not if it is `NO`.

Any ideas? Is this a bug? I've searched online and through documentation and can't find a reason that UITabBarController shouldn't be able to present a view this way.

Answer (score 3):

This definitely sounds like a bug. I'd suggest you file a [bugreport](http://bugreport.apple.com) with Apple. If it's blocking your project, you could submit it through one of your support incidents with Apple, and if they find it really is a bug they'll refund that support incident (so you don't loose anything). If it isn't a bug, they'll be able to give you a solution.

Comment: confirmed the bug on xCode 4.2, iOS SDK 5.0.